# Row number isn't working with Paginated Pages

Tags: php, pagination

I've implemented a very simple pagination my page. Everything's working fine except the row numbers (serial numbers of each row). On the first page everything works fine, when I go to the next page, row numbers resets back to 1.

Here's the server side code (PHP) for Pagination -

```
  $page     = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $per_page = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 10;

  // Start Positioning of page
  $start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $per_page) - $per_page : 0;


  $records = $conn->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM menu_items INNER JOIN dish_type ON dish_type.dish_type_id = menu_items.dish_type_id INNER JOIN cuisine_type ON cuisine_type.cuisine_type_id = menu_items.cuisine_type_id LIMIT {$start}, {$per_page}");
  $records->execute();
  $results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  // Total pages required calculation
  $total = $conn->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
  $pages = ceil($total/$per_page);
  $counter = 0;
```

I'm using the $counter variable to echo out row numbers.

And below is the HTML table that I'm using -

```
<?php foreach ($results as $menu_item_data) : ?>
<tr>
<td>
<?= ++$counter;  ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: dont use short tags (`<?`) as they're not used on all servers, and can pose issues. Change it to `<?php`

Comment: Also, you gotta define your $counter before the loop, and you actually echo after the foreach is done not inside.

Comment: @Kray I think short tags are supported by most Servers these days. Are they not? I've had no problem with the short tags on my server so far. But it's a good point. Thank you.

Comment: Somethnig like `$i = 0;
foreach ($some as $somekey=>$someval) {
    //xyz
    $i++;
} echo $i;`

Comment: short tags are not recommended. it doesnt save antyhing, or add any value to save 2 keystrokes. Complete the tag, and you'll be safe period regardless if the server has short tags enabled in the php.ini.

Comment: @Kray Would you be so kind and modify my code to further explain? I'm using a table and the row numbers are being displayed inside <td> element within a table. The table data is generated by the foreach loop. If I echo the $counter variable after the loop ends, how will it generate the <td> element for each row? I'm sorry I'm still new to this, just trying to grasp the concept. :)

Comment: ok, i'll post what I believe you're after.

Comment: I believe your issue may be coming after you view the next page. Are you passing any parameters in the URL? I reread your question so that I understood it, and you say "when I go to the next page, row numbers resets back to 1" which would give me the indication that you're not passing a URL parameter to let your pagination script know you're viewing the next page.

Comment: I'm passing parameters in the URL - here's how the page URL looks like - ----/main-menu-item-view.php?page=2&per-page=10

Comment: Think of it like this. First step is to gather total record count, and then divide that by how many records per page. That will return a number of pages available. For that example you have 55 records. Each page has 10 records, would give you 6 pages. You click second page, it doesn't know what you're doing unless you pass a parameter to it indicating to the script to go to page 2 of 6 available. and display the second data set.

Comment: Check out `http://php-ease.com/classes/pagination.html`

Comment: @Kray Thanks! I'm however not using Object Oriented PHP entirely. So it's not helping me much. :)

Comment: OOP is great stuff IMO ;) @KhairulAlam

Comment: No doubt about that. I'm slowly picking up on things. :) @Kray